# how to pass object through asp.net web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, object

**1. Class Library Project** C# , I have created Customer Class Library Project which has only one class file called "Customer.cs"

```
namespace CustomerClassLibrary
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**2. Web Service Project**

I have added CustomerClassLibrary dll under the reference folder

Created two methods

```
[WebMethod]
public string HelloWorld()
{
    return "Hello World";
}

[WebMethod]
public string GetAllTickets(CustomerClassLibrary.Customer C )
{
    string statuscode;

    if (C.FirstName=="JOHN")
    {
        statuscode = "success"; 
    }
    else{
        statuscode = "failure";
    }


 return statuscode;
}
```

**3. Client Application (C# Windows application)**

Added CustomerClassLibrary dll under the reference

Added WebService reference under the Service Reference folder (Created Proxy class)

```
var ss = new SRMUserRegServiceReference.SRMUserRegistrationSoapClient();
```

Button 1 Click:

```
string status = ss.HelloWorld();
Console.WriteLine(status);
```

When I execute this , I can able retrieve "Hello World status Successfully.  Everything looks good.

Button 2 click :

```
CustomerClassLibrary.Customer C;              
C.FirstName = "John";
C.LastName = "TEST";

string returnString =ss.GetAllTickets(C);

Console.WriteLine(returnString);
```

Here, When I tried to pass "Customer C object in GetAllTickets(C) methods, I am getting error.

Can you please guide me how do I pass "Single Object" through the web service?

Two Errors, I am getting :

Error   1

> The best overloaded method match for 'ClientApplicationCallWebService.SRMUserRegServiceReference.SRMUserRegistrationSoapClient.GetAllTickets(ClientApplicationCallWebService.SRMUserRegServiceReference.Customer)' has some invalid arguments    Testing\ClientApplicationCallWebService\ClientApplicationCallWebService\Form1.cs   50  34  ClientApplicationCallWebService

Error   2

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'CustomerClassLibrary.Customer' to 'ClientApplicationCallWebService.SRMUserRegServiceReference.Customer' Testing\ClientApplicationCallWebService\ClientApplicationCallWebService\Form1.cs   50  51  ClientApplicationCallWebService

Comment: What error are you getting? Also try to mark your class Customer as [Serializable]

Comment: Your code wont even compile - GetAllTickets() doesn't return anything.

Comment: return statusCode at the end of your method.  What happens when you set a breakpoint in the method?

Comment: When I tried to execute the client application, I am getting two errors.

Comment: Hey Isma,  Could you please guide me how do I mark Customer class as [Serializable]

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
CustomerClassLibrary.Customer C =  new CustomerClassLibrary.Customer();              
C.FirstName = "John";
C.LastName = "TEST";

string returnString =ss.GetAllTickets(C);

Console.WriteLine(returnString);
```

Comment: Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'ClientApplicationCallWebService.SRMUserRegServiceReference.SRMUserRegistrationSoapClient.GetAllTickets(ClientApplicationCallWebService.SRMUserRegServiceReference.Customer)' has some invalid arguments Testing\ClientApplicationCallWebService\ClientApplicationCallWebService\Form1.cs 50 34 ClientApplicationCallWebService

Comment: Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'CustomerClassLibrary.Customer' to 'ClientApplicationCallWebService.SRMUserRegServiceReference.Customer'  Testing\ClientApplicationCallWebService\ClientApplicationCallWebService\Form1.cs 50 51 ClientApplicationCallWebService

Comment: I am getting the above Errors.

Comment: I tried the above code, still I am getting the same error.

Comment: Seems like you have an issue with double reference in your code.

initialize your customer object with

ss.CustomerClassLibrary.Customer c = new ss.CustomerClassLibrary.Customer();

Answer (score 0):

```
            ClientApplicationCallWebService.SRMUserRegServiceReference.Customer C = new ClientApplicationCallWebService.SRMUserRegServiceReference.Customer(); 


        C.FirstName = "JOHN";
        C.LastName = "TEST";

        string returnString =ss.GetAllTickets(C);

        Console.WriteLine(returnString);
```

Finally, I found the answer, I created instance for Customer Class the below, now I can able to pass the object.  Thanks all

```
        ClientApplicationCallWebService.SRMUserRegServiceReference.Customer C = new ClientApplicationCallWebService.SRMUserRegServiceReference.Customer();
```